# Can not add new Element into Vector while inside a for loop

Tags: java, swing, for-loop, listener, jbutton

I'm creating a search form. When the user input a string in the textField and click on button Search, the program will browse through the Vector, if Vector has any element, which has the name LIKE the input string, I will print that element's name to the console.
If Vector has no element, which has the name LIKE the input string, I will add a new object that has the name is the input string into the Vector.
For example : when I input "John" on the textField and press button Search,If the Vector has an element which has a name "John", I will print "John" to the console. If the Vector doesn't have "John", I will add a new Student that name's "John" into the Vector.
My problem is, I put the Search function in the btnSearch's action listener, but the Search function looks like doesn't work inside a button's action listener. I try to fix it half of a day but still don't understand what did I wrong. So please help me !. Here is my entire runnable program :
 * class Group which contains many students :

```
public class Group {
protected Vector<Student> listStd;

public Group() {
}

public Group(Vector<Student> listStd) {
    this.listStd = listStd;
}

public Vector<Student> getListStd() {
    return listStd;
}

public void setListStd(Vector<Student> listStd) {
    this.listStd = listStd;
}

public void addStudent(Student std){
    listStd.add(std);
    std.setGr(this);
}

public void search(String name){
    for(int i=0;i<this.getListStd().size();i++){
        if(this.getListStd().get(i).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)){
            System.out.println(this.getListStd().get(i).getName());
        }
        else{
            this.getListStd().add(new Student(name));
            System.out.println("not found");
        }
    }
}

public void print(){
    for(Student std:this.getListStd()){
        System.out.println(std.getName());
    }
}
}
```

- class  Student :

  ```
  public class Student {
  protected String name;
  protected Group gr;

  public Student(){

  }

  public Student(String name){
      this.name = name;
  }

  public void setName(String name){
      this.name = name;
  }

  public String getName(){
      return this.name;
  }

  public Group getGr() {
      return gr;
  }

  public void setGr(Group gr) {
      this.gr = gr;
  }



  @Override
  public String toString() {
      return this.getName();
  }
  }
  ```
- UI class which performs the UI and main function :

  ```
  public class UI extends JFrame{
  JTextField txtSearch;
  Vector<Student> listStd;
  JButton btnSearch,btnDisplay;
  Group gr;

  public UI(String title){
      super(title);
      addControls();
      addEvents();
  }

  public void addControls(){
      listStd = new Vector<Student>();
      gr = new Group();
      gr.setListStd(listStd);
      gr.addStudent(new Student("Kurapika"));
      gr.addStudent(new Student("Leorio"));
      gr.addStudent(new Student("Hisoka"));
      gr.addStudent(new Student("Meruem"));
      gr.addStudent(new Student("Gon"));
      gr.addStudent(new Student("Killua"));

      Container con = getContentPane();
      JPanel pnMain = new JPanel();
      pnMain.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pnMain, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

     JPanel pnSearch = new JPanel();
     JLabel lblSearch = new JLabel("Write student name to search ");
     txtSearch = new JTextField(10);
     pnSearch.add(lblSearch);
     pnSearch.add(txtSearch);
     pnMain.add(pnSearch);

     JPanel pnButton = new JPanel();
     btnSearch = new JButton("Search");
     btnDisplay = new JButton("Display");
     pnButton.add(btnSearch);
     pnButton.add(btnDisplay);
     pnMain.add(pnButton);


      con.add(pnMain);
  }

  public void addEvents(){
      btnSearch.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          @Override
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              gr.search(txtSearch.getText());
          }
      });

      btnDisplay.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          @Override
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              gr.print();
          }
      });
  }

  public void showWindow(){
      this.setSize(300,200);
      this.setState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
      this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      this.setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
      UI ui = new UI("Test");
      ui.showWindow();
  }
  }
  ```

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [MCVE]" what you have instead is a big code blob and no few specifics.

Comment: I editted the question

Comment: It's still pretty confusing. try to reduce the code to the absolute minimum required to recreate the problem and also describe your problem clearly - 'it doesn't work' is hard to interpret. Beside the outline of your program functionality that you have, describe specifically (including any errors, etc) - what you did, what happened and what you expected to happen.

Comment: You are adding element to this.getListStd() within the loop. Not a good idea!

Comment: I know it, but I don't know any other ways to :(

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you are asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: It's not my homework friend, I'm trying to add a new element in Vector inside a listener , and I come here to be helped to find the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could maybe (or maybe not) be the source of your problem but I still have to point out this error in your code:

```
public void search(String name){
    for(int i=0;i<this.getListStd().size();i++){
        if(this.getListStd().get(i).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)){
            System.out.println(this.getListStd().get(i).getName());
        }
        else{
            this.getListStd().add(new Student(name));
            System.out.println("not found");
        }
    }
}
```

In your `for`-loop you are actually saying that for each element you have to check if its name equals the given name: if it does you print it, else you add a new member. After it, go to the next element and do the same.
So you are doing this for **all your elements in your list**. You are creating a new `Student` each time there is a an element that doesn't have the same name as the name described by the argument. You should not create the new element inside the loop. Not only you are adding the same name multiple times but you also are increasing the size of your list while you're using it in your loop condition! Only add elements to your list outside the loop, when you finished checking all elements. You can only be sure that the name doesn't exist once you finished checking all your elements in the list. You just need an additional boolean to memorize if it has been found or not. So your code should (at least) be like this:

```
public void search(String name){
    boolean found = false;
    for(int i=0;i<this.getListStd().size();i++){
        if(this.getListStd().get(i).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)){
            System.out.println(this.getListStd().get(i).getName());
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if(! found){
        this.getListStd().add(new Student(name));
        System.out.println("not found");
    }
}
```

This may (not) solve your problem. I wanted at least to point out this fundemental error.

PS: In general, don't change the size of a collection (arraylist, set, ...) if you are using that size in your loop condition! (except if it is really really really your intention...but that's rare)

Good luck

Comment: It works like a miracle, you saved my life friend :((
thank you so much !!!